# How to prevent sensitive fields updated by client

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, shiro

For example, in an web appliation, I have a user model:

```
class User{
    String username;
    String email;
    String passowrd;


    boolean active;
    Set<Role> roles;
}
```

The following operations are supported:

```
1 guest can register(create a new user)
2 user can upate its info
3 user with role of admin can set the `active` and `roles`
```

At the server side we use the `SpringMVC` to get the model `User` directly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected Result create(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    .....
}
```

So far so good with normal workflow, but think about someone(not admin user) send that:

```
/user  HTTP/Update

{
    "username":"jk",
    "active":true,
    "roles":[{
        id:"role_admin_id"
    }]
}
```

If this requset is accepted, the user `jk` will have the role of `super_admin`, which is not expected.

How do you protect that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @RequestBody User user you sent is just a regular object you wanna update. It's not Spring Security User. If you want to define User as in spring security user, you' ll have to implements UserDetails. Do you already have spring security setup correctly? I don't know if you use xml or java configuration. If you use java configuration, you can control the access by roles as follow:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()                                                                
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
    // ...
    .formLogin();
}
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#authorize-requests